# Is the [maven-3] tag no longer necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Virtually all [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) questions are about [maven-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-3).

There are no newer Maven versions (and it is unlikely that there will be one in the near future) and Maven 2 is dead and gone.

Should these tags somehow be merged?

EDIT:

Next Maven will be Maven `4.0.0`. So this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: You could make them a synonym (or post a request), no?

Comment: Logically, they are not synonyms, but practically, they are. I am not sure what the best course if action is.

Comment: As a non subject matter expert, could you explain me a little more about "*and it is unlikely that there will be one in the near future*" and the context? Maybe could you add some references? Why it is not likely that Maven get updated by a new version? This is crucial important for this request.

Comment: what happens when maven 4 comes out?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Maven 3 was introduced in 2010. Maven 2 lasted 9 years, and Maven lasted 12. There's usually overlap between versions before they're turned EOL, There's no announcement of Maven 4, so it'll at least be a couple years before Maven 4 starts being a thing, assuming a cycle of about 10-12 years per version. To be fair, 9 and 10 years include the phase-out period. We'll at least have a couple years, at which point we're probably gonna get [maven-4] and reiterate the same discussion in 15-20 years or so

Comment: @Zoe You really think you can extrapolate with 2 data points? There is no set schedule, but Maven 4 is quite close. It will also be a short release, basically a stepping stone to Maven 5. Certainly not 12 years. They were considering skipping 4 altogether. If you want to know more, [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw9ypxJWMnA) with Robert Scholte (project lead) explains.

Comment: @Michael Skipping maven 4 and only releasing 5 still means there were 10+ years between 3 and the next version. Doesn't mean version 4 took 0 years to release. Secondly, if you google `"maven 4"` or `"maven 5"`, two pages stand out: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+4.0.0 (notice "last modified on Sep. 06, 2015"), and a [draft for POM v5](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/POM+Model+Version+5.0.0). Both 2 and 3 had alpha and beta, and 3 had it [for an entire year](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) before releasing

Comment: I can't find any code or any new canonical references aside early development of 4 and 5, so "soon" is arguably relative in this context and not gonna be for at least a couple years. I'm also unable to find any tags or mentions of early releases or even early development on the code itself - it's purely theoretical from what I can tell. How they decide to label a stepping stone doesn't say anything on how the next real version (taking 5 as the real version, and 6 as the next real one) will take, but the release cycles are generally slow.

Comment: @Zoe You are comparing the wrong numbers anyway. You are comparing EOL. Between releases, Maven 1 -> 2 was one year (2004-2005). Maven 2 -> 3 was five years (2005-2010). So if what we care about is when the next version will be released, which is what would invalidate any assumption that Maven == Maven 3, assuming a 12 year release cycle, when the current and longest major release has existed for 10 years is clearly objectively wrong.

Comment: @Michael except by comparing time from release to EOL, you actually see the real timeframe for releases. Yeah, versions were released long before the previous version went EOL, and that's the point. There's about 5-10 years of phasing out the previous version after the new one is released. If they release a temporary Maven 4, there's realistically a high chance Maven 3 will continue to remain the current version, because especially companies prefer LTS over a stepping stone. I also said the 9 and 10 years included the phaseout in my first comment.

Comment: Honestly though, this is why I dislike version tags - the border for when they should be merged into the main tag is extremely unclear. The same applies to languages: when, if at all, should they be merged into the main tag? What's to be done about people using [maven-3] for general Maven problems that aren't specific to Maven 3? [python-3] is heavily overused for general Python problems because of a few incompatible changes between Python and Python 3 - doesn't make python-3 the primary tag

Comment: There's also this page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Core+Roadmap

Comment: rather than editing, you should post a separate answer explaining why your original question is no longer valid, then accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven 4.0.0 is currently developed. So this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

> Should these tags somehow be merged?

I think the best way would be to synonymize [maven-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-3) with [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) as master tag.

Replacement would in fact require that all occurences of [maven-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-3) (4,850 questions at the time of writing) need to be removed (burninated), and either replaced with [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) or just leaving that one.
This is a heavy process, which needs efforts from a lot of users.

Synonymizing on the other hand, would simply re-tag future questions where the [maven-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-3) tag is applied with [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven).

Some reference:
**[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)**

Comment: Moderators can merge tags that are funtionaly the same thing.

Comment: It can probably be automated.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with merging. The ideal situation would be that Maven 1 questions are tagged as "maven-1" and Maven2/3 questions are tagged as "maven". Maven 1 is functionally and structurally really different from Maven 2/3 while Maven 2/3 in usage are very similar (or should I say: nearly identical). If there ever comes a Maven 4 I don't really expect that to be much different either, whatever changes there are will be under the hood. They're not going to mess with the established infrastructure now, that would break a significant amount of tooling and builds.

Retagging everything to do with Maven 1 seems like a big waste of time though so let's not go there.

Comment: The whole point of a major version jump is to be able to make breaking changes, to provide features or improvements that would otherwise be too disruptive. Anything which can be "under the hood" has already been done, or will be done, without incrementing the major version. If you want to know what 4 and 5 might contain, there's no need to speculate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw9ypxJWMnA

Comment: @Michael Well I add "overhaul internals but keep the external interface in-tact" to the list of reasons to do a major version jump. Just because you can make breaking changes, does not imply that it will be done. Interesting video though, thanks for sharing.